# How to run celery task only once amongst multiple replicas?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, celery, amazon-elasticache, celerybeat

I have a bunch of fargate instances on AWS, and they have celery running on them locally with Elasticache for redis. Due to Auto Scaling policies instances keep spawning and de-spawning, the issue is, the celery tasks that I have run as many times as there are replicas of my server. Can anyone suggest a way to prevent this behaviour?

The celery beat tasks takes a bunch of rows in the database and performs certain operations on them, I tried adding a "processed" flag on the rows to indicate that they've been processed, but since all the replicas start the task at the exact same time, this solution fails.

Currently the scheduler for celery beat is set to DatabaseScheduler.

Here's the config that I have right now.

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = os.environ.get('CELERY_BROKER_URL', 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0')
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = os.environ.get('CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND', 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0')
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'US/Central'


CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = { 
    'withdraw_money_daily': {
        'task': 'app_name.tasks.perform_the_task',
        'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=0),
    }   
}              

REDIS_HOST = os.environ.get('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost')
CHANNEL_LAYERS = { 
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [(REDIS_HOST, 6379)],
        },  
    },  
}
```

Command that starts the celery

```
celery -A app worker -l info -E
celery -A app beat -l info --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler
```

Comment: running celery independent of the web server instance was the answer to this.

Comment: Did you just deploy your Django app to a different server then and use it to run Celery?  I assume you had to someone integrate into your database since you're using it as a scheduler.

Comment: Yes that's what I did previously, later I deployed celery to another server and just used my "main" server to serve the app. @Scott

Comment: if you ever have time, it would serve a lot of people to write a tutorial in a blog post somewhere.  Especially if you have any good tips for doing a multi-environment RDS database without exposing it to the internet.  I'm probably going to have to do this soon so I will try to write one too :)

Comment: I actually have one in my drafts, I'll post the content here as well in form of an answer. @Scott

Comment: You are doing a great service to EB-chained developers everywhere!

Comment: @Sahil Still waiting on the answer. We're facing the same issue, this will help us a lot.